# Div Overlay and Blocking UI

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, overlay, blocking

In my ASP.net project I have a web page with some design time controls and some controls like a table is generated at run time and appended to a div on the page say a container div without any height,width,top,bottom set. I want to show an overlay div only and only over my container div so only the dynamic generated content is blocked and not rest of the page.

Most important is I am trying to achieve this by NOT setting the TOP,Right,Left,Bottom of my divs, reason being I want to do this on rest of my web pages where static and dynamic contents are different but approach is same (some static content and dynamic content is added to a blank div below static contents).

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

you should use [`Block UI` jQuery plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/),

for element blocking use `$.block()` function see more documentation on site

Comment: please see my EDIT I do not want to set any position for my divs